# Pipe Console App to file from batch file

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, console-application

I have a console app (Visual Studio - VB), it runs, it does it's job.

I also have a batch file that runs the program and everything, but I want the output of my console app to also send to a text file.

This is my current batch, which creates the text file, but nothing is in it.

```
Start "" "C:\Users\wrossi\Desktop\NetLogOnSysInfo Solution\NetLogOnSysInfo Project\bin\Debug\NetLogOnSysInfo Project.exe" -all >>%ComputerName%.txt
Exit
```

Not sure if the batch is wrong, or if I should look at my program. Also, how do I define a path so I can put the output file exactly where I want it?

Comment: The `>>` redirection applies to `Start` command. You should escape it as follows: `^>^>`

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close to what I think you want to do:

`c:\console.exe > c:\output.exe`

`c:\console.exe` or wherever the location of your console app `>` redirect stdout (use `>>` to append) `c:\output.txt` or wherever you want to create the text file.

Hope this helped.

Also just in case:

`type stdin.txt | console.exe > stdout.txt`

In the above example you can redirect an input from `stdin.txt` and pipe it into `console.exe` then redirect the output of `console.exe` to `stdout.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
"C:\Users\wrossi\Desktop\
 NetLogOnSysInfo Solution\NetLogOnSysInfo Project\bin\Debug\NetLogOnSysInfo Project.exe" 
    -all > %ComputerName%.txt
```

No need to use `Start`.

Answer (score 0):

I found one code recently after searching alot 
if u wanna run .bat file in vb or c# or simply 
just add this in the same manner in which i have written
here is the code

```
 code > C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\output.txt
```

just replace word "code" with your .bat file code or command and after that the directory of output file